# C# Making opacity part of other window

Tags: c#, opacity

after a long time of searching I found out how to do opacity on other windows. Heres the code if anyone needs (you need DLLImport):

```
        IntPtr foundWindow = new IntPtr(0);
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("FL");
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            foundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;
        }

        SetWindowLong(foundWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(foundWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(foundWindow, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
```

Also, I got a question, is it possible to make part of window opacity? Maybe if I started process, instead of found it? Thanks;).

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're trying to ask. Is it possible to create a window in which only parts of it are transparent/opaque? Yes. In windows forms theres a property called TransparencyKey which basically acts as a colour that will always be drawn as transparent (so if it's set to green, anything green in the window will be transparent). WPF provides more robust and better looking options.

Comment: My question was about windows outside project, but thanks for info

Comment: I almost finished it:D look code: http://pastebin.com/qgyZTehB